# scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated scrolling too slow

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Based on the page change of a paged UIScrollView, I'm calling `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated` to the table specifics for that page that's in display.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth/2)/pageWidth)+1;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:page];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

However, the animation of the automatic scrolling is happening too slow. Is there a way to make this animation more snappy?

Comment: Are you talking about running on the device or the simulator?

Comment: On both the animation is slow.

Comment: Try to use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` without animation and add that line into a `UIView` animation block for which you can set the animation duration.

Comment: I added my comment as an answer, if you want you can mark it as accepted so your question will not appear on the unanswered section.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A fast solution might be:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:aSmallValue animations:^{
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                              atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop 
                                      animated:NO];
}];
```

Comment: @danypata I want to know the difference between your method and Oscar Swanros's method?

Comment: The problem was that the scroll is to slow for the `scrollToRowAtIndexPath", "scrollToRowAtIndexPath" speed is computed depending on the content size, but if you want the same speed for any content size, then you can use my method.

Comment: Even with no animation it's slow for me