# UITableView :scrollToRowAtIndexPath or setContentOffset animation speed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

Lets say i have 10 rows displaying numbers 1 to 10. I need scrolling effect like 1 to 10 to 1to 10... I achieved this using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` and `setContentOffset`. The issue i want to slow down the scrolling before i apply my logic to stop this recursion. So is there a way that i can decrease the scroll speed for `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`.
? Please do not suggest, decelerationRate as scrolls here are all programmatic, no user interactions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:durationInSeconds animations:^(void){
    [tableView setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];
}];
```

You just need to calculate the offset. If your rows have equal heights, then your offset is simply calculated:

```
CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, indexPath.row * rowHeight);
```

and if the height varies then you need to do this:

```
CGFloat offsetY = 0;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i <= indexPath.row; i++) {
    offsetY += [tableView.delegate tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, offsetY);
```

EDIT:

You can also use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:animated:` method with `animated` set to `NO` in the animation block instead of `setContentOffset`, and then you don't have to calculate the offset yourself.

Comment: Sounds good. Do u mean that once i decide to slow down, i come out of my circular scroll recursion logic and do the above to reach my intended row which will give a slow scroll effect?

Comment: Yes, this is to slow down the scrolling, and you set the duration with 'durationInSeconds' parameter in animateWithDuration method. As Alex suggested in another answer, you can also use scrollToRowAtIndexPath:animated: method with animated set to NO in the animation block instead of setContentOffset, and then you don't have to calculate the offset yourself.

Comment: Yeah, Tried that. WOrks.

Answer (score 2):

Just call your scrollToRowAtIndexPath or setContentOffset methods inside 
[+(void)animateWithDuration:animations:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:) block.

Check these answers for more details:

[Change the speed of setContentOffset:animated:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404745/change-the-speed-of-setcontentoffsetanimated)

[scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated scrolling too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071442/scrolltorowatindexpathatscrollpositionanimated-scrolling-too-slow)